# multiple character input to char in C

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char ch,ch1;
   scanf("%c",&ch);/*input ab here*/
   scanf("%c",&ch1);
   printf("%c %c",ch,ch1);
   return 0;
}
```

Why this produces `a b` as output. We don't enter any input for second variable but it still got assigned. Could anyone explain the behavior.

You can check the output [here](http://ideone.com/bonwYG) if you want.

Comment: `"%c"` scans one byte of input, which consumes `a`, and `b` is still in the input stream when the second `scanf()` gets called. That's just how `scanf()` works.

Comment: You don't handle the newline, `%c` doesn't skip blank lines.

Comment: Are you trying to put multiple characters in a `char`? That's what the question title looks like. I haven't messed around with `<stdio.h>` because I use C++ and `<iostream>`, but `%c` looks like, at a glance, the syntax to represent a `char` in `<stdio.h>`. Correct me if I'm wrong, please. :)

Answer (score 2):

> We don't enter any input for second variable

That's not true, `"%c"` in `scanf` reads one character, after it processes the input `a`, the  `"%c"` in the next `scanf` then reads the next input character `b`.

Comment: But dont you think scanf ends the input after encountering a newline character. Here We enter the new line character after typing 'ab'. Then how come b goes to second variable.

Comment: @anujpradhan Add another `scanf("%c",&ch2);` after the second, you'll see the newline character in `ch2`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you entered 2 characters in the 1st input while the program expects just 1: the 2nd is pending until the next call to `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

this may get you rid of the situation

```
scanf("%c",&ch);/*input ab here*/
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&ch1);
```

**EDIT**
Your actual problem is that `ch1` is being assigned with the newline character(or the space as tried in IDEONE simulator)

To check that :
enter your values without any separation.

Comment: still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf can do multiple scans:

```
char a1, a2, a3, a4;
scanf("%c%c%c%c", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);
```